# Add QLayout to QSplitter?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I want to create a QWindow containing a left and a right layout. But I also want to add these layouts to a QSplitter so that I can drag to resize the size of these layouts. How can I do that?

Comment: A `QSplitter` already has a layout. Just add two widgets to it (each with its own layout), and then add other widgets to the layouts of those widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add widgets with layout to your splitter.
The following code should do the work.
It will add two vertical widgets, in horizontal orientation (left and right)

```
    QWidget * poLeftWidget = new QWidget(this);
    QWidget * poRightWidget = new QWidget(this);
    QVBoxLayout *poVLeftLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QVBoxLayout *poVRightLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    poLeftWidget->setLayout(poVLeftLayout);
    poRightWidget->setLayout(poVRightLayout);

    QSplitter * poSplitter = new QSpitter(Qt::Qt::Horizontal, this);
    poSplitter->addWidget(poLeftWidget);
    poSplitter->addWidget(poRightWidget);
```